# What is the reason why galvanic series is in it's specific order?

Tags: electrochemistry, electronegativity, noble-metals

I'm trying to understand why galvanic series molecular entities are in the order they are in.

Why does $\ce{Cu(s)}$ reduce $\ce{Ag^{2+}}$ ions but not $\ce{Pb^{2+}}$ ions?

there seems to be some kind of small correlation with electronegativity but there's a lot of exceptions for it to be true.

ie:
the electronegativities of Li and K are 0.98 and 0.82 respectively and K is more noble, but K and Ca electronegativities are 0.82 and 1 and Ca is more noble in this case?

If you go down the galvanic series the nobility of metals sometimes increase steadily for a long way but then start decreasing with no seeming connection to electronegativity or octets or half octets.

ie from Mg to Sn the electronegativity increases step by step. (going through the nobility order)(Mg 1.31, Al 1.61, Zn 1.65, Fe 1.83, Ni 1.91, Sn 1.96, Pb 2.33 but then decrease, H 2.2, Cu 1.9 and then increases again Ag 1.93, Au 2.54)

So is there any connection between electronegativity and the nobility of a metal? and if so why is there so much exceptions?

If not then what determines the nobility of a metal?

does ionization of a metal notably change the molecular entitie's electronegativity?

Here's a picture to illustrate with the order of nobility and arrows to clarify the direction.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "galvanic series molecules"? A molecule is an electrically neutral object, consisting of 2 or more atoms, connected by covalent chemical bonds. Then there is a molecular entity, covering all kinds of neutral or charged smallest particles of matter.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent need of clarification, objections, down-voting or closure.

Comment: You may want to review search results for the targeted search [site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu OR site:wikipedia.org  series electrochemical Gibbs energy](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Alibretexts.org+OR+site%3Ahyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu+OR+site%3Awikipedia.org++series+electrochemical+Gibbs+energy) eventually using alternative keywords.

Comment: @Väinö For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) as a comfortable method to add chemical equations.  Here, it was applied only in the one line where it is most suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Seems I have a lot to learn about the culture here and I will start with the sources you provided.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration [SE meta - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) // [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)  // [Advanced formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is relation between metal electronegativity and the position in the electrochemical / galvanic metal series. But the metal electronegativity is just one of the factors determining the position.

The position is determined by the value of the standard [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) of the reaction.

$$\ce{M^{n+}(aq) + $\frac n2$ H2(g) -> M(s) + n H+(aq)} \quad \quad ΔG^{\circ}_\text{r}=ΔH^{\circ}_\text{r} -TΔS^{\circ}_\text{r} \tag{1}$$

and the related standard reduction potential of the formal "half-reaction":

$$\ce{M^{n+}(aq) + n e- -> M(s)}\quad \quad E^{\circ}_{\ce{M/M^{n+}}} = - \frac {ΔG^{\circ}_\text{r}}{nF} \tag{2}$$

where $F \approx \pu{96485 C mol-1}$ is the [Faraday constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_constant).

The metal position on the galvanic series is determined by the value of this potential, the most negative (the least inclined to oxidize anything) for alkali metal ions, the most positive (the most inclined to oxidize anything) for precise/inert metal ions.

The sign of the reaction Gibbs energy change determines the reaction spontaneity. Spontaneous reactions have this sign negative.

The relation of the potential and the Gibbs energy may seem on the first look suspicious, until one reminds himself the equation of electrostatics $\text{d}E = U . \text{d}q$, where $E,U,q$ are potential energy, potential and electric charge, which defines the favourite unit of energy $\pu{1 eV}$.